# graph is not showing in screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I followed one tutorial to create a graph. Here is that [Part 3 tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-graph-with-quartz-2d-part-3/), but while I run my graph line is not showing up. Here is my code:

**Gridview.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define kGraphHeight 300
#define kDefaultGraphWidth 900
#define kOffsetX 0
#define kStepX 50
#define kGraphBottom 300
#define kGraphTop 0
#define kStepY 50
#define kOffsetY 10

@interface GridView : UIView

@end



**GridView.m**




    #import "GridView.h"

    @implementation GridView

    - (void)drawLineGraphWithContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
    {
        //float data[] = {0.7, 0.4, 0.9, 1.0, 0.2, 0.85, 0.11, 0.75, 0.53, 0.44, 0.88, 0.77, 0.99, 0.55};
         float data[] = {0.7, 0.4, 0.9, 1.0, 0.2, 0.85, 0.11, 0.75, 0.53, 0.44, 0.88, 0.77, 0.99, 0.55};

        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.5 blue:0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]);

        int maxGraphHeight = kGraphHeight - kOffsetY;
        CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, kOffsetX, kGraphHeight - maxGraphHeight * data[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(data); i++)
        {
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, kOffsetX + i * kStepX, kGraphHeight - maxGraphHeight * data[i]);
        }

        CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);

    }




- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect



{


    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawLineGraphWithContext:context];

    // Draw the background image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.6);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]);
    CGFloat dash[] = {2.0, 2.0};
    CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0.0, dash, 2);

    // How many lines?
    int howMany = (kDefaultGraphWidth - kOffsetX) / kStepX;

    // Here the lines go
    for (int i = 0; i <= howMany; i++)
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, kOffsetX + i * kStepX, kGraphTop);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, kOffsetX + i * kStepX, kGraphBottom);
    }

    int howManyHorizontal = (kGraphBottom - kGraphTop - kOffsetY) / kStepY;
    for (int i = 0; i <= howManyHorizontal; i++)
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, kOffsetX, kGraphBottom - kOffsetY - i * kStepY);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, kDefaultGraphWidth, kGraphBottom - kOffsetY - i * kStepY);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, NULL, 0); // Remove the dash
}
```

**viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

    UIScrollView *scroller;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

**viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GridView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(kDefaultGraphWidth, kGraphHeight);

}
```

Why am I not able to generate the graph to display. Please help me to solve. Thanks

Comment: where are you calling the drawLineGraphWithContext ? I dont see any code that calls that method, you probably missed it somewhere

Comment: i am new to ios. really dont know where to call that. In that tutorial they din call any where

Comment: in that tutorial they din't call that `drawLineGraphWithContext`

Comment: im sure they would call it.

Comment: if i want to call `drawLineGraphWithContext` in  inside `drawRect` means how to call that. kindly help me please

Comment: you can just say [self drawLineGraphWithContext:context]

Comment: i did `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect



{
    
    [self drawLineGraphWithContext:context];
`

Comment: it getting me error `use of undeclared identifier: context`

Comment: place that line below the CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
in the drawRect method

Comment: after call that method also not able to see the graph

Comment: see my update post. i edited all.but not working

Comment: Show the code related to GRidView in theUIViewCOntroller? Where did you initialise the gridview ?

Comment: see i am new to ios, i used that tutorial to follow to learn. but really not understanding where to intialize to work

Comment: Try to do this in your view did appear. GridView *gv=[GridView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];

Comment: kindly please see my viewcontroller.m

Comment: and then [ self.view addSubView:gv];

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this method in your view controller.m

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   GridView *gv=[GridView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];

   [ self.view addSubView:gv];

}
```

Comment: error `no visible @interface for `uiview` declare the selector `addsubview` `

Comment: add that method below the viewDidLoad in your view controller.m

Comment: they din use any grid view, please see this introduction part for that tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-graph-with-quartz-2d/

Comment: after this above link only i have move to see part 3 tutorial

Comment: ok then, does your scrollview contains any other view ? Did you gave the file owner name as GridView for your scrollview ?

Comment: s . i have place one view on above scrollview. that view called `gridview`

Comment: YOu need to add a UIView to the scrollView in your storybaord, and give the file name for the UIView as grid view

Comment: yes i did that also in story board. No i am not use teamview

Comment: try giving the view a color and see it it appears on the device